# Center Openlayers map based on amount of polygons

Tags: javascript, openlayers, extents

I have number of polygons on my map, how can i center the map and set zoom so all fits in the map,

I managed to get the center of each polygon and put a marker on the center using  getExtent() would it be the same for the map?

heres my code
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bqyqog?editors=1010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34041570/open-layers-3-center-the-map-based-on-extent-on-vector-layer#34042795, you can add this to your JS code:

```
map.getView().fit(source.getExtent(), map.getSize());
```

J.